# How to include a condition with a multiindex filter in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a filter which consists of a multiindex. I want to apply a condition on only the values that are contained in that multiindex. Is it possible?

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

# this multiindex comes from a model so it is fixed and we cannot know the values in advance
fixed_multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bar','one'), ('foo', 'one')])

df_multinidex_and_condition = df.loc[(fixed_multiindex) & (df[0] > -1.3)]
```

The error

```
Output error TypeError: other must be a MultiIndex or a list of tuples
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df_multinidex_and_condition = df.loc[df.index.isin(fixed_multiindex) & (df[0] > -1.3)]
print (df_multinidex_and_condition)
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.217679  0.821455  1.481278  1.331864
foo one  2.672172  0.464802  0.845930 -0.503542
```